# How would I apply rotations to both qubits in a 2 qubit system?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, entanglement, matrix-representation, linear-algebra

Say I have the two qubit system $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}$.

I have two 2x2 unitary gates, one is a rotation by $\theta$ radians and the other is a rotation by $-\theta$ radians. How would I apply one of these rotations to one qubit and the other to the other qubit? Can I do this with a single 4x4 gate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your $2 \times 2$ unitary gate is an $RY$ rotation. Then you can create your $4 \times 4$ gate as follow:
$$U = RY(\theta)\otimes RY(-\theta)$$

Now, when apply $U$ to your state, you simply act $RY(\theta)$ to the first qubit and $RY(-\theta)$ to the second qubit.

To see this more explicitly, first note that your state $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{|01\rangle + |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ can be represented in a quantum circuit as:

[image]

Then now applying $U$ is equivalent to adding appropriate $RY$ rotation to the appropriate qubit, which is:

[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is I would generate the 4x4 and then multiply it with my state vector.

Comment: If you want to do it explicitly by hand then yes. What I am trying to write is that in your question, it seems to me like you try to implement certain one qubit gate says $U_1$ on qubit and another one qubit gate  says $U_2$ to the other qubit. If that is the case then your $4 \times 4$ unitary gate is $U = U_1 \otimes U_2$. In my answer, I took $U_1$ and  $U_2$ to be $RY$ rotations...

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help. :)